# How can I make my search form work with uppercase and lowercase

Tags: javascript, uppercase, lowercase, search-form

I want my search form to work with uppercase and lowercase. So whenever I input something that's lowercase it will also show me te uppercase results in the table I'm searching in.

Here's my javascript

```
function searchFunction() {
var searchText = document.getElementById('database_search_bar').value;
var targetTable = document.getElementById('database_table');
var targetTableColCount;

for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
    var rowData = '';

    if (rowIndex == 0) {
       targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
       continue; 
    }

    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
        rowData += targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;
    }

    if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
        targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
    else
        targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
 if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
```

to:

```
 if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) == -1)
```

This way, for comparison, you will be using lower case strings only. I.e. if `searchText` was "Lorem Ipsum" and `rowData` was "I HAVE LOREM IPSUM WITHIN", they'll become "lorem ipsum" and "i have lorem ipsum within" respectively - thus, they'll match.

[`String.prototype.toLowerCase()` reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Also note that in ES6 you have [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) that might be used for what you're doing. It'll read a bit better - however it's not supported in IE at the moment.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!

Comment: Yea I realised. I commented to fast, sorry! But it works now.

Comment: @robindehaan Glad it did. If you accept my answer, I'll cross 20k points mark by the way! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore case, may be you should make both side to be upper case or lower case.

In your case, you can use `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` on `rowData` and `searchText`.

```
var upperData = rowData.toUppercase();
var upperText = searchText.toUppercase();
if (upperData.indexOf(upperText) == -1) {
  //Not Found
}
else {
  //Found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative:

The trick is homogenize the comparison.

How to do this homogenization?

- Just convert the elements to compare to the same type.
- But they are strings, yeah but `A` is different to `a`. So, we may lowercase all or uppercase all. But, How?
- Using [`toLowerCase()`](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) or [`toUpperCase()()`](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) methods.

I created a `notFound()` that lowercase `rowData` and `searchText` and then returns `false` if the indexOf is `-1` otherwise will return `true`. Sorry, It took me long time to fill the table with countries and continents.

```js
var searchButton = document.getElementById('search_button');
searchButton.addEventListener('click', searchFunction)

function searchFunction() {
  var searchText = document.getElementById('database_search_bar').value;
  var targetTable = document.getElementById('database_table');
  var notFoundText = document.getElementById('not_found');
  var targetTableColCount;
  var hasResult = false;
  
  notFoundText.innerHTML = '';
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
    var rowData = '';

    if (rowIndex == 0) {
      targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
      continue;
    }

    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
      rowData += targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;
    }

    if (notFound(rowData, searchText)) {
      targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
      hasResult = true;
    }
  }
  if (!hasResult){
    notFoundText.innerHTML = 'There are no results.';
  }
}

function notFound(rowData, searchText){
  return rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) === -1;
}
```

```css
table td {
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
Search Text: <input id="database_search_bar" type="text" name="fname"><input id="search_button" type="submit" value="Search">
<p></p>
<table id="database_table" >
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Continent</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Brazil</td>
    <td>South America</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jordan</td>
    <td>Asia</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mauritania</td>
    <td>Africa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>United States of America</td>
    <td>North America</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Netherlands</td>
    <td>Europe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oman</td>
    <td>Asia</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Honduras</td>
    <td>South America</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lithuania</td>
    <td>Europe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="not_found" ></div>
```